# send a number by zeromq pyzmq

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I want to send lots of numbers via zeromq but converting them to str is inefficient. What is the best way to send numbers via zmq?

Comment: If you're processing so many messages it's slow for Python to convert int <--> string, you might need to rethink your exact architecture/language choice.

Comment: What kind of numbers (int/float, how large) are you sending, how many in a message, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that converting numbers to `str` is inefficient.  And yet, unless you have a truly exotic network, that is exactly what must occur no matter what solution is chosen, because all networks in wide use today are byte-based.

Of course, some ways of converting numbers to byte-strings are faster than others.  Performing the conversion in C code will likely be faster than in Python code, but consider also whether it is acceptable to exclude "long" (bignum) integers.  If excluding them is not acceptable, the `str` function may be as good as it gets.

The `struct` and `cpickle` modules may perform better than `str` if excluding long integers is acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

A few options:

- use python's struct.pack / struct.unpack methods e.g. struct.pack("!L", 1234567)
- use another serializer like [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/)

Comment: +1 for msgpack. It is an ideal fit for Python because you can turn a dict into a msgpaxk message as easily as a JSON object. And it handles integers and floats quite efficiently.